# How can I build a linear additive model in Scikit?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to build a model which takes the predication of a simplified intermediate-model *f_I* and multiplies it by some coefficient *c_p* and adds the result of some general model *f_g*:

[image: Formula]

The coefficients ***C*** are then optimized to fit the data.

The general model I am choosing is an RBF model, and so far I have fitted the RBF to the data:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import  RBF

# The true formula
beta = np.pi
omega = 10*np.pi
alpha = 1
phi = .5*np.pi

def f(t):
    return alpha*np.tanh(beta*t)*np.sin(omega*t + phi)

# Generate some test data
t = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)

X_train = np.random.choice(t.reshape(-1), size=12).reshape(-1, 1)
y_train = f(X_train)

kernel = RBF(length_scale=0.5, length_scale_bounds=(0.01, 100.0))

gpr = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, random_state=1)
gpr.fit(X_train, y_train)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=200)
ax.plot(t, f(t), 'grey', label="True")
ax.plot(X_train, y_train, 'ko', label="Training")
ax.plot(t, gpr.predict(t.reshape(-1, 1)), 'b--', label="GLM")
fig.legend()
```

[image: RBF]

However, I do not know how to implement this linear additive model. I have attempted to make a function for the intermediate model:

```
def IM(t):
    return t*np.sin(omega*t)
```

[image: IM]

And then change the kernel in the GaussianProcessRegressor to something like:

```
kernel = IM()*ConstantKernel() + RBF(length_scale=0.5, length_scale_bounds=(0.01, 100.0))
```

However, this doesn't work because the IM() needs to be a class of some sort that works with the Scikit library. However, I can’t find much information online on how to do this.

Is making a custom kernel for the intermediate model, *f_I* the right approach? If so, How do I build a custom kernel to work with Scikit?

The paper that I'm following to implement this is [available here, in section 2.2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.3816.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the fit function can be ameliorated or corrected, but I think it's a good base.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF, ConstantKernel
from sklearn.base import RegressorMixin


class MyModel(RegressorMixin):
    def __init__(self, model_fi, model_f_g):
        self.model_fi = model_fi
        self.coef_c_p = ConstantKernel()
        self.model_f_g = model_f_g

    def fit(self, X=None, y=None):
        self.model_fi = self.model_fi.fit(X, y)
        min_erreur = np.inf
        for i in np.arange(0.2, 1.0, 0.1):
            self.coef_c_p = ConstantKernel(constant_value=i)
            res = (self.model_fi.predict(X) * self.coef_c_p.constant_value) + self.model_f_g(X)
            erreur = self.score(y, res)
            if erreur < min_erreur:
                min_erreur = erreur
                best_value = i
        self.coef_c_p = ConstantKernel(constant_value=best_value)
        print(best_value)

    def predict(self, X=None):
        return (self.model_fi.predict(X) * self.coef_c_p.constant_value) + self.model_f_g(X)

# The true formula
beta = np.pi
omega = 10 * np.pi
alpha = 1
phi = .5 * np.pi


def f(t):
    return alpha * np.tanh(beta * t) * np.sin(omega * t + phi)


# Generate some test data
t = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)

X_train = np.random.choice(t.reshape(-1), size=12).reshape(-1, 1)
y_train = f(X_train)

kernel = RBF(length_scale=0.5, length_scale_bounds=(0.01, 100.0))
gpr = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, random_state=1)


model = MyModel(gpr, RBF(length_scale=0.5, length_scale_bounds=(0.01, 100.0)))
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(model.predict(X_train))
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist for this fit function? Why is it the way it is? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69516024/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: I've spent a long time fiddling around with this problem. I think I have eventually got it to work using this method but swapping the `GaussianProcessRegressor` with  `KernelRidge`. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

- Utilize the inbuilt Sum and Product functions in `gaussian_process.kernels`

```
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF, Sum, Product, ConstantKernel
def IM(t):
    return t*np.sin(omega*t)
kernel_custom= Product(IM(X_train) ,ConstantKernel())
kernel = Sum(kernel_custom, RBF(length_scale=0.5, length_scale_bounds=(0.01, 100.0)))
```

- Other option is to create Custom Kernels in RBF can be created as per the official documentation, sample code as
  [shown here in line 1423](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/gaussian_process/kernels.py#L1423) where you need to implement `__call__` as `StationaryKernelMixin`, `NormalizedKernelMixin` already implements `diag` and `is_stationary`. Code added for reference

```
class RBF(StationaryKernelMixin, NormalizedKernelMixin, Kernel):

    def __call__(self, X, Y=None, eval_gradient=False):
        """Return the kernel k(X, Y) and optionally its gradient.
        Parameters
        ----------
        X : ndarray of shape (n_samples_X, n_features)
            Left argument of the returned kernel k(X, Y)
        Y : ndarray of shape (n_samples_Y, n_features), default=None
            Right argument of the returned kernel k(X, Y). If None, k(X, X)
            if evaluated instead.
        eval_gradient : bool, default=False
            Determines whether the gradient with respect to the log of
            the kernel hyperparameter is computed.
            Only supported when Y is None.
        Returns
        -------
        K : ndarray of shape (n_samples_X, n_samples_Y)
            Kernel k(X, Y)
        K_gradient : ndarray of shape (n_samples_X, n_samples_X, n_dims), \
                optional
            The gradient of the kernel k(X, X) with respect to the log of the
            hyperparameter of the kernel. Only returned when `eval_gradient`
            is True.
        """
```

Comment: Kernel functions unfortunately do not work like that, they require two inputs X and X' and then output a scalar. The kernel describes the covariance between the two values

Comment: As I mentioned earlier creating a custom kernel will solve your problem and the errors you are facing, do look into the document which will help you create custom kernel in right format. Hope it goes well for you